# Mustache.js is not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, json, templates, rendering, mustache

I'm using Mustache.js and I have the following template to render a drop-down list:

```
<select name="{{listName}}">
    {{#items}}
    <option value="{{id}}">{{name}}</option>
    {{/items}}
</select>
```

and the json object that I pass to the render method is:

```
items:[
    0: {id:1, name:Actor}
    1: {id:2, name:Director}
    2: {id:3, name:Producer}
    3: {id:4, name:Executive Producer}
    4: {id:5, name:Assistant Producer}
    5: {id:6, name:Scriptwriter}]
listName: "occupation"
```

the line that does the rendering is:

```
var html = Mustache.render(template, jsonData);
```

html variable contains:

```
<select name>
</select>
```

and what is rendered is an empty drop-down list.
Though in Mustache [demo page](http://mustache.github.io/#demo) if i paste my template and the Json data it renders fine.
Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Are the key value pairs quoted?

Comment: @Sushanth-- Yes they are, I just copied the whole object from the console so it showed up like this.

Comment: Did you check for any errors in the console

Comment: No errors in console. it even renders in the demo page of mustache

http://mustache.github.io/#demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After research I have found what was going wrong. when logging the typeof the variable jsonData, it turned out to be a string and not an object.

So all I had to do is:

```
object = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
var html = Mustache.render(template, object);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why it has happened: demo page that you refer to uses Maustache.to_html method. That [definitely works well](http://jsfiddle.net/3SDWm/):

```
document.getElementById('target').innerHTML =
    Mustache.to_html(document.getElementById('template').innerText, jsonData)
```

But at homepage of Javascript library .render() method is named.

Comment: it didn't really answer my question, but upvoted for pointing me in the right direction, Thank you. I'm going to post my answer.